# Try Except Error: not giving output on wrong input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is working fine except that it's not showing the except error 8 > arrivalHour > 23

```
while True:
    try:
        arrivalHour = int(input("Enter your time of arrival | No Parking from Midnight 00:00 to 07:59 Am: "))
    except 8 > arrivalHour > 23:
        print("Wrong Input of Arrival Hour, Please Try Again")
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again")
        continue

    if 8 <= arrivalHour <= 23:
        break
```

Comment: This is NOT the way to use `try/except`. It catches **Exceptions**, not **conditions**. I am not even sure why that works

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to Python; like second day of learning, can you guide on adding that condition in the code>

Comment: You already do, in the end there with the `if`. You should go over the official [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) to help you learn

Comment: I tried on adding an IF statement but that didn't work either, it ignores the statement. Thank you for the Tutorial site, it seems nice tho I've been learning from youtube mainly CS DOJO which is great.

Comment: One thing to note, the condition `8 > x > 23` is not possible (an equivalent expression is `x < 8 and x > 23`). If x is greater than 23 it is not less than 8. As @Tomerikoo said, that second `except` isn't for catching certain values, it's for catching Exceptions which typically means that some kind of error happened. What you want is to check it with `if` or `if/else`. Since you already have an `if` to determine whether you need to `break`, you can add an `else` that only executes when you don't want to break. Which, in this case, is when your user inputs a value outside of the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write

```
while True:
    arrival_hour = int(input("Enter your time of arrival | No Parking from Midnight 00:00 to 07:59 Am: "))
    if 8 <= arrival_hour <= 24:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Input of Arrival Hour, Please Try Again") 
        continue
```

Comment: Why create a `range` when you can use simple mathematical check (which is actually in the question)?